# Scala map, zipWithIndex and infix form

Tags: scala, coding-style

I have next code:

```
List.tabulate(n, n)(_ * _).zipWithIndex.map{case (list, index) => index :: list}
```

I want to write it as suggested by http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html, so in infix form:

```
val n = 10
val list = List.tabulate(n, n)(_ * _) zipWithIndex map{case (list, index) => index :: list}
```

but this stops from compiling. Why? And are there any better explanation when I can use infix and when can I not, rather than a link I gave? It doesn't look like it explains the chained calls of different Arity, like I'm doing

Comment: In the [same document](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#suffix_notation) : _Although the syntax is used by some DSLs, it should be considered deprecated, and avoided._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `zipWithIndex` does not take parameters so you cannot write it in infix position. Try:

```
val n = 10
val list = List.tabulate(n, n)(_ * _).zipWithIndex map { case (list, index) => index :: list }
```

However, if you meant suffix, that is as Peter mentioned deprecated and discouraged. If you insist though, you would have to `import scala.language.postfixOps`.

And even then you would not be able to combine suffix with infix notation.

```
import scala.language.postfixOps
val n = 10
val list = List.tabulate(n, n)(_ * _) zipWithIndex 
val result = list map { case (list, index) => index :: list }
```